# How to define a percentage change function for quarterly HPR for non-continuous dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, stock

I have a large dataframe containing the time series on a set of 5 bonds. I need to calculate the quarterly holdings period return for eac stock. My dates go from 2013 to 2021. Is there any way I can do this without tedious work?

Here is a snippet from my dataframe which shows one of the five bonds.

```
date,isin,asset_name,oas_bp,moody_rating,price
11/01/2013,US18683KAC53,CLIFFS NATURAL RESOURCES INC,392.5617321,Baa3,88.974998
12/01/2013,US18683KAC53,CLIFFS NATURAL RESOURCES INC,392.5842828,Baa3,87.367996
11/02/2013,US18683KAC53,CLIFFS NATURAL RESOURCES INC,392.5617321,Baa3,88.974998
12/02/2013,US18683KAC53,CLIFFS NATURAL RESOURCES INC,393.4720759,Baa3,86.835999
11/03/2013,US18683KAC53,CLIFFS NATURAL RESOURCES INC,392.5617321,Baa3,88.974998
12/03/2013,US18683KAC53,CLIFFS NATURAL RESOURCES INC,393.2453897,Baa3,87.073997
11/04/2013,US18683KAC53,CLIFFS NATURAL RESOURCES INC,385.458694,Baa3,89.027
12/04/2013,US18683KAC53,CLIFFS NATURAL RESOURCES INC,394.9549884,Baa3,86.370003
11/05/2013,US18683KAC53,CLIFFS NATURAL RESOURCES INC,391.1068957,Baa3,87.774002
12/05/2013,US18683KAC53,CLIFFS NATURAL RESOURCES INC,395.1016716,Baa3,86.275002
11/06/2013,US18683KAC53,CLIFFS NATURAL RESOURCES INC,394.1597822,Baa3,87.648003
12/06/2013,US18683KAC53,CLIFFS NATURAL RESOURCES INC,394.6755953,Baa3,86.264999
11/07/2013,US18683KAC53,CLIFFS NATURAL RESOURCES INC,393.7169591,Baa3,88.099998
12/07/2013,US18683KAC53,CLIFFS NATURAL RESOURCES INC,394.6755953,Baa3,86.264999
11/08/2013,US18683KAC53,CLIFFS NATURAL RESOURCES INC,403.9096138,Baa3,85.853996
12/08/2013,US18683KAC53,CLIFFS NATURAL RESOURCES INC,394.8397875,Baa3,86.264999
11/09/2013,US18683KAC53,CLIFFS NATURAL RESOURCES INC,403.9096138,Baa3,85.853996
```

I have defined DataFrames for each bond individually, and have the following code which calculates the percentage change over one quarter for one of the bonds.

```
mask = (df[cliff]['date'] >= '2013-1-1') & (df['date'] <= '2013-3-31')
 print(df.loc[mask])

print(100*(df.loc[mask].iloc[-1]['price']-df.loc[mask].iloc[0]['price'])/df.loc[mask].iloc[0]['price'])
```

But I have 5 bonds over 9 years which would mean I have to do this 180 times. How could I define a function to do this for me?

Comment: Please add a snippet of the dataframe with the relevant columns to your question. This should help other users to understand your question better.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.